# Make a SQL for exclude certain data

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a somewhat far-fetched question I want to know if there is any way to solve it:

I have a table called PRODUCTS with these attributes:

```
ID, NAME, DATE
```

I have a table called PRODUCTS_STATUS with these attributes:

```
ID, PRODUCT_ID, STATUS_ID, DATE
```

I have a table called STATES with these attributes:

```
ID, STATUS_NAME
```

Now, as you have seen, it will be about:
STATES_PRODUCTS will have many STATES of PRODUCTS and STATUS will be many times in PRODUCT_STATUS
This means that PRODUCT_STATUS has a many-to-many relationship between states and products, since a PRODUCT will go through different state transitions.

Perfect up to there, it turns out that I have this case suppose:

PRODUCTS_STATES

```
ID, PRODUCT_ID, STATUS_ID, DATE
1      1            1      00:00:00
2      2            1      00:00:00
3      3            1      00:00:00
4      1            5      00:00:00
```

I am doing a query at the moment between PRODUCTS and PRODUCT_STATUS, at first I made a query where I told him to show me all the PRODUCTS that have in PRODUCT_STATUS the STATUS_ID= 1

But if you realize for example the PRODUCT_ID is twice in the table PRODUCT_STATUS with the STATUS_ID = 1 and 5

Ask:

Is it possible to make a query where it shows me all PRODUCTS with PRODUCT_STATUS equal to 1 but where PRODUCTS_ID that already has another state are excluded?

that is, for this example, I want to know if we could see PRODUCTS 2 and 3 because if they see 1 it already has another state.

Notice I have this query made but it is not useful for what I want:

```
   SELECT
    *
   FROM
   products
   inner join product_status in products.id = product_status.product_id
   WHERE
   product_status.status_id not IN ( 
   SELECT
   product_status.id_status
   FROM
   product_status
   WHERE
   product_status.id_status = 5

   )
```

Obviously they will realize that the query returns all the products with STATUS_ID = 1 but I no longer want to see PRODUCT 1 because I am no longer interested.
I would like to exclude all those PRODUCTS that have 1 and 5.

I hope you can give me an idea of ​​how it is done. Thanks.

Comment: The not in sub query also needs to test product code. You could also use an existence check (not exists)

Comment: Hello, yes i resolved the problem. Thank u

Answer (score 0):

I recommend `NOT EXISTS` instead of `NOT IN`, because `NOT IN` has strange behavior when working with `NULL` values (and `EXISTS` often optimizes better than `IN`).

But your version is quite close:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM products p JOIN
     product_status ps
     ON p.id = ps.product_id
WHERE ps.status_id = 1 AND
      NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM product_status ps2
                  WHERE ps2.product_id = ps.product_id AND
                        ps2.status_id <> 1
                 );
```

Note that this introduces tables aliases (abbreviations for the tables).  This makes the query easier to write and to read.